# How to register a global handlebar helper

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, browserify

**handlebarhelpers.js file**

```
var $ = require('jquery'),
Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
Backbone = require('backbone');


module.exports.ifCondhelper = function (Handlebars, options)  { 


    Handlebars.registerHelper('ifequal', function(value1, value2, options) {
        if(value1 === value2) {
            return options.fn(this);
        }
        return options.inverse(this);
    });

}
```

**Template**

```
{{#ifCondhelper.ifequal type ../../notificationMessage.SkuMappingNotAvailableMessageP1}}
<li notid="{{id}}"><a href="#">{{../../../notificationMessage.SkuMappingNotAvailableMessageP1}}: Something Something {{../../../notificationMessage.SkuMappingNotAvailableMessageP2}}: Something Something</a> </li>
{{/ifCondhelper.ifequal}}
```

I am using Browserify and Backbone how do i access the helper globally in browserify? Please help

Comment: It appears to me as if you deleted and reposted this question, as I saw it mid afternoon yesterday and now appears to have been asked only 4 hours ago. You should not delete and repost your questions as a method of getting attention for them. If I'm wrong about what you have done, then I apologize.

Comment: No my question was a little different before i found a solution to it so deleted it shouldn't have done it though sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to declare it with `registerHelper`, you actually can't do it as a separate module

```
// helpers.js

var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

Handlebars.registerHelper('ifequal', function(value1, value2, options) {
    if(value1 === value2) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});

module.exports = {} // This line not needed, just wanted to show you export nothing
```

and now in your handlebars compile function somewhere in your code

```
// Just including this module with require will 
// register the helpers to the Handlebars global object

require('./helpers.js');

// Now the rest of your code

Handlebars = require('handlebars');

var template = Handlebars.compile(...);
...
...
```

Pretty much that's it.

And in your template you use it like this :

```
{{#ifequal type ../../notificationMessage.SkuMappingNotAvailableMessageP1}}
<li notid="{{id}}">
   <a href="#">
   {{../../../notificationMessage.SkuMappingNotAvailableMessageP1}}: Something  Something {{../../../notificationMessage.SkuMappingNotAvailableMessageP2}}: Something Something</a>
</li>
{{/ifequal}}
```

Comment: It still get an error Uncaught Error: Missing helper: 'ifequal'

Comment: Check my demo http://jsbin.com/lapidixidu/1/edit?html,js,console,output . In my case it is working. May be it's because of your `require` statement

Comment: i think its because of Browserify have to figure out a way to use it globally it doesn;t work for me saw your example works well. But not in my code

Comment: It's hard to make a demo with browserify, because there's no such webapp that I can easily show, but I've done this. Try to clean as much of the code as you can until it is working and gradually add after this. See which modules are executed, because I'm pretty sure your Handlebars helpers module is either loaded after your `compile` statement or not loaded at all!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77583/discussion-between-vini-and-drinchev).